# RPM Spec file unpack tar.gz into multiple locations

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

With the help of [this](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/) manual im trying to generate my first RPM.
My goal is to generate an rpm that unpacks my file `project.tar.gz` into multiple destination directories.

lets say I have the following sturcture in the tar.gz:

```
/part-one
   /file-one.py
   /file-two.py
/part-two  
   /file-one.py
   /file-two.py
   /subdirectory
       /file-one.py
       /file-two.py
```

I want part-one to be installed into `/opt/project-one/libs/`
and part-two into `/opt/project-two/libs/specific-dir/`

Do I need to place all files that are in the tar.gz inside the %files body item like:?

```
%files
/part-one/file-one.py
/part-one/file-two.py
/part-two/file-one.py
/part-two/file-two.py
/part-two/subdirectory/file-one.py
/part-two/subdirectory/file-two.py
```

And how do I specify the target of those files?

I understood when I use:

```
%prep
%setup -q
```

The content of the tar.gz is automatically unpacked and I do not need to add an unpack commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `%setup`, you would need a `%install` section and then a `%file` section.

`%install` section installs/copies the unpacked source (your tarball) into appropriate target directories (`/opt/....`). Here is an example

```
%setup -q

%build
# empty

%install
# create target dirs
install -p -d -m 0755 /opt/project-one/libs
install -p -d -m 0755 /opt/project-two/libs/subdirectory

# copy files
install -m 0644 part-one/*.py /opt/project-one/libs/
install -m 0644 part-two/*.py /opt/project-two/lib/subdirectory

%files
# This should take care of all files inside these dirs.
/opt/project-one/
/opt/project-two
```